# Are they still Captors?

Tags: word-choice

I have a question... Say people kidnapped you and then you escaped a little while later. You run away and they are chasing you currently. Are they still your captors, or are they now something else?

Answer (score 4):

"Captors" is an appropriate word, but depending on timescale "pursuers" may be more accurate. Once you are recaptured they would then again be your captors, so using the term throughout should be fine. Context comes into question as to which term might be better to use in a particular place.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are still captors, or if you want to emphasize the timeline of the escape, then they become the former captors.

Answer (score 0):

**Depends on context.**

They still captured you, so yes, they are still "captors".

But calling them that implies you are talking in a context where the fact they captured you is their defining feature. Such as being currently captive or wondering about the motives for the capture.

If the context of discussion is avoiding pursuit, it usually is not terribly important that they already captured you once. Call them something relevant in the current context instead.